# Dynamic where condition in sybase stored procedure

Tags: sap-ase

I am storing where clause statements in the database table, after that I am getting and using in select statement.

Here is my sybase query,

```
"INSERT table(RUN_ID,RUN_DATE,GRGR_ID,SGSG_ID,COLUMN_NAME,ERROR_CODE)SELECT @pnRunId,getdate(),GRGR_ID,SGSG_ID,@COLUMN_NAME,@ERROR_CODE from table1_exct where + @WHERE_CLAUSE"

@WHERE_CLAUSE = '@IKA_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL'
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you experiencing difficulties: (i) when inserting where-clause into table? (ii) when selecting where-clause from table and running the resulting SQL? (iii) other?

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you can insert your where clauses but don't know how to run them.

That would be hard but not impossible.  You'd have to use a cursor or a loop to build up a piece of Sql in a VARCHAR.

```
declare @Sql VARCHAR(2000)

select @Sql = 'INSERT table(RUN_ID,RUN_DATE,GRGR_ID,SGSG_ID,COLUMN_NAME,ERROR_CODE)SELECT @pnRunId,getdate(),GRGR_ID,SGSG_ID,@COLUMN_NAME,@ERROR_CODE from table1_exct where ' 

while 1 = 1 
begin
    declare @claus VARCHAR(200)
    SET ROWCOUNT 1
    SELECT @claus = where_clause from some_table
    select @sql = @sql + @claus
    delete some_table where where_clause = @claus
    set rowcount 0
end
```

This has 2 things to think about - it doesn't provide for WHERE and AND for the first and subsquent clauses (I'm sure you can do that,) and it deletes your where clauses from their source (you can get them all into a temp tab first to get round that.)

If your clauses are all on the same column, you can have a list of LIKE expressions in a column and join to that using the LIKE operator - that can be handy.

Anyway at the end of the above, run the sql:

EXEC(@Sql)

Answer (score 0):

Abe's answer is correct, if you build a dynamic SQL query as a varchar, you can exec it via EXEC(@varname) if this is only a 1-off issue.

You could consider use XML functionality in ASE 15.  We actually went through this exact same exercise for a in-depth business rules engine at one point, and were fairly set on using the xml features inside ASE 15 to merge computed columns, case statements and where clauses inside XML text in the DB.

Here's some info  http://www.sypron.nl/xml.html

So, I believe a solution like this could solve your issue a little more elegantly than dynamic SQL.

We ended up not using it because we couldn't enable XML support in production (legacy 2k page issue)...but I feel like this could solve your problem if your problem is large enough to support the workload of implementing something that could use it (We ended up just using java.)